#  How to insert custom field in typo3 Dam module at custom location?

Tags: typo3, dam

I introduced my custom field in Dam modules. it works fine. I want to display my custom field in overview tab(the first tab) when editing the document. Now its appearing in the last tab.

How to do this.

This is my ext_tables.php lines which adds the field into dam module

```
t3lib_extMgm::addToAllTCAtypes('tx_dam','custom_field;;;;111');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t3lib_extMgm::addToAllTCAtypes(
  'tx_dam', // table
  'custom_field;;;;111', // your field definition
  '', // at which types it should appear (f.e. in table tt_content 'textpic' or 'image')
  'after:title', // before: or after: the field in the TCA
  );
```

f.e. see there:
http://api.typo3.org/typo3v4/45/html/classt3lib__ext_mgm.html#a61b2e2deb5d29cfb871e905b040dd416

Comment: That's a dead link. :(